# Chrome embedded PDF download filename

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf, download, filenames

I have the following that visually embeds the pdf on my page:

```
<embed src="modules/files/actions/get_file.php?id=134" 
type="application/pdf" 
style="border: 0px; width: 100%; min-height: 500px" 
title="Project Report project_102587.pdf">
```

when I use the download button of the chrome internal pdf viewer, the suggested filename shows as get_file, but I want it to be Project Report project_102587.pdf like in the title attribute.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in get_file.php add header that contains filename (add it before data stream)

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="Project_Report_xxxx.pdf"');
```

Answer (score 0):

embed is to get file name from url

from

`modules/files/actions/get_file.php?id=134`

to

`modules/files/actions/get_file.php/Project_Report_project_102587.pdf?id=134`